# Error message now showing up as top layer

Tags: vbscript

I made a program that should keep having error messages pop up and then disappear on their own, it works, but the error messages (after the first one) are usually below the current window open, making it not seen. How can I make this show up? Thanks

```
Const TIMEOUT = 5
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Do Until True = False
    WScript.Sleep 3000
    objShell.Popup "Error1", TIMEOUT
Loop
```

Comment: Working with errors like this is bad practice. If you receive 100 errors, you would have to click ok for 100 times. If that were to happen to me as user, I would get frustrated. Ideally you want to queue up the errors and either show it in one error, or even better, put them in a logfile and just one error message that says: Errors triggered, see log file. The entire error message popup routine would be suspended until ok is pressed, but errors continuously are being added to the log.

Comment: I see what you mean about this being bad practice. I was not planning on using it for anything official, just to experiment with and see if it could work. I'm trying to learn more about the language, and I was trying to learn why the errors aren't on top and how to fix it. Thanks

Comment: The reason this happens is because when your program spawns more than one window, only the currently visible message is sent to the top. The rest is placed in a queue. When another app is activated  and you click that ok window, the focus goes back to the other window, while Windows continues to place popups in the background. This is because in the past people were trolled with a stream of popups which would basically stop someone from using windows. This is a way to fix that.